# Is whipped cream a liquid for the purposes of airport security?

Tags: europe, airport-security

I'm going to travel to visit my mother from Stockholm to Brussels. I'm thinking about bringing a traditional Swedish pastry called semla for her from her favourite bakery. They are sweet rolls filled with whipped cream and an almond paste. I would estimate that a semla contains about a decilitre of whipped cream and almond paste, but they obviously don't have a declaration of contents stating the exact amount. Does anyone know if I can bring something like this through security at Arlanda without too much hassle?

Comment: I can only say that I had some duck with pretty liquid sauce in my carry-on on three trips at least and nobody batted an eye at it.

Comment: I have seen on an airport "if you can poor it or spread it, it is a liquid and not allowed through security." So if you are unlucky they will tell you to eat or bin it. (if you have hold luggage that would be safe.)

Comment: I've taken food a lot of times with chilli sauce or spreadable cheese etc on it, in the UK airports I've never had a problem with this, but it really just depends! Worst case they will take them off you and it could cause you a delay whilst they check your bags, so go slightly early in case!

Comment: The phrasing in the UK (of course, Stockholm isn't in the UK) typically refers to "liquids, gels or pastes". By the letter of the rules, these pastries would not be allowed. However, the practical question remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to give it a try (worst case scenario I would have pastries for breakfast before passing through security). It was no problem to take them through security. I placed the bakery box separately to be scanned and no one so much as batted an eye at it.

Answer (score 4):

The restrictions for carry-on are usually phrased like this:

> The current restrictions for liquids, aerosols and gels from ICAO and in effect in most countries are that they must be in containers 100ml or equivalent, placed in a transparent resealable plastic bag with max capacity 1-litre. (As found on the [International Air Transport Association](https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/ops-infra/baggage/Pages/check-bag.aspx) website)

Although a cream stuffing is definitely not a liquid, with a bit of imagination (or maybe even technically) it can be called a gel.

But I don't think that any security officer would consider cakes and pastries as "containers" that may have a carrying capacity exceeding that 100 ml limit.

Comment: I can't understand your last sentence -- are you saying that you think security officers will allow or deny the pastries? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It's fairly clear.  I don't see how that last sentence (in normal English parlance) can be read as anything but "they will allow the pastries".

Comment: @Ertai87 I don't know what to say. I'm a native speaker of English and I can't make head or tail of it.

Comment: I think they're saying that a cake / pastry is not considered a container, therefore are not applicable to the rule.

Comment: The question is then if the cake or pastry is not considered a container and the rule is not applicable are they exempt from the rule or forbidden from luggage on the plane as they do not fit the criteria. I have not seen semla myself, but a simlar pastry like a cream horn  or profiteroles could if it was a large one contain more than 100ml of cream.